# Convert 2 Date Columns to Datetime in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have tried several things to try and convert 2 date columns into a single datetime column and I keep getting errors. My data in a df called dfn2 looks like this:

```
   Plant_Name YYMMDD     HHMM vel(m/s)
0  CA I       20180101   100  6.197878
1  CA I       20180101   200  6.768227
2  CA I       20180101   300  6.779299
3  CA I       20180101   400  7.008282
```

And, I'm trying to end up with a single datetime column like:

```
   Plant_Name date_time               vel(m/s)
0  CA I       01/01/2018 1:00:00 AM   6.197878
1  CA I       01/01/2018 2:00:00 AM   6.768227
2  CA I       01/01/2018 3:00:00 AM   6.779299
3  CA I       01/01/2018 4:00:00 AM   7.008282
```

I have tried something like this:

```
dfn2[['YYMMDD','HHMM']] = dfn2[['YYMMDD','HHMM']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M.%f')
```

and get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '20180101' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M.%f' (match)
```

Comment: a little bit of context is required, because we could do this by matching the string against regular express, and transforming the values we need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string is incorrect.
Try this instead:

```
>> pd.to_datetime(df["YYMMDD"].astype(str)+df["HHMM"].astype(str).str.zfill(4), format="%Y%m%d%H%M")
0   2018-01-01 10:00:00
1   2018-01-01 20:00:00
2   2018-01-01 03:00:00
3   2018-01-01 04:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The `zfill` is done to make sure every HHMM entry is exactly four characters long.

Comment: I think the argument of the ```zfill``` should be ```4``` and the slicing wouldn't be necessary: ```pd.to_datetime(df["YYMMDD"].astype(str)+df["HHMM"].astype(str).str.zfill(1), format="%Y%m%d%H%M")``` else the first 2 rows display the wrong time

Answer (score 0):

Your format string is wrong because in your dataset you do not have the '-' date separator.
So for the YYMMDD column you have this '%Y%m%d'.

I can't fully help you because I do not understand the HHMM column format.

Comment: Sorry, HHMM is HH = hour, MM = minute in my original column header above. in the case above, it is hour 0100, 0200, 0300, 0400 or 1,2,3,4 AM. The YYMMDD is year or YY = 2018, month or MM = 01, and day or DD = 01.